# Non-scalar cast: `Box<FnMut<&Any>>`

Tags: casting, rust, traits

I am trying to return a closure that takes an `&Any` as argument. Following code returns a compiler error.

```
trait Selector {
    fn id(&self) -> i64;
    fn selector(&self) -> Box<FnMut(&Any, &mut Any)>;
}
struct TypedSelector<TSource, TTarget> {
    id: i64,
    select: Box<FnMut(&TSource, &mut TTarget)>,
}
impl<TSource, TTarget> Selector for TypedSelector<TSource, TTarget>
    where TSource: 'static,
          TTarget: 'static
{
    fn id(&self) -> i64 {
        self.id
    }
    fn selector(&self) -> Box<FnMut(&Any, &mut Any)> {
        self.select as Box<FnMut(&Any, &mut Any)>
    }
}
```

The compiler error is the following:

```
error: non-scalar cast: `Box<for<'r, 'r> std::ops::FnMut(&'r TSource, &'r mut TTarget) + 'static>` as `Box<for<'r, 'r> std::ops::FnMut(&'r std::any::Any + 'static, &'r mut std::any::Any + 'static)>`
   --> src\main.rs:190:9
    |
190 |         self.select as Box<FnMut(&Any, &mut Any)>
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Am I missing some type annotations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

First, what you're trying to do (cast from `FnMut<&TSource, &mut TTarget>` to `FnMut<&Any, &mut Any>`) isn't valid.  If you had succeeded you would have been able to call a function expecting a `&TSource` with a different type - so you'd have broken type safety and caused undefined behaviour.

To fix this, you can wrap it in a closure which downcasts the `Any` and handles any errors (in this example it will `panic` as I use `unwrap`):

```
    Box::new(
        move |a, b| {
            let a = a.downcast_ref().expect("a was the wrong type.");
            let b = b.downcast_mut().expect("b was the wrong type.");
            (self.select)(a, b)
        }
    )
```

At this point the next problem becomes apparent: `TypedSelector` owns the original boxed closure (`select`), but this new closure needs access to it.  There are three ways to pass values in Rust, and none work as is:

- By value (move) won't work unless `selector` takes `self` by value (and hence destroys it in the process)
- By immutable `&reference` wouldn't allow you to call the `FnMut`
- By mutable `&mut reference` similarly can't be done from the immutable `&self`.

So something needs to change. I'm going to arbitrarily pick the most fully featured but heavy-weight option, and use `Rc<RefCell<T>>` to have shared reference-counted pointers to the internally-mutable `FnMut`; this might not be the option which is best for your situation:

```
fn selector(&self) -> Box<FnMut(&Any, &mut Any)+'static> {
    let wrapped = self.select.clone();
    Box::new(
        move |a, b| {
            let a = a.downcast_ref().expect("a was the wrong type.");
            let b = b.downcast_mut().expect("b was the wrong type.");

            // Mutably borrow the shared closure (checked at runtime)
            let mut f = wrapped.borrow_mut(); 

            (&mut *f)(a, b)
        }
    )
    //self.select as Box<FnMut(&Any, &mut Any)>
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d70256fceab073c128d9778e83a40ca8&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Comment: I know what `unwrap` is tempting, however it might be best to teach newcomers to use `expect` instead. It does make diagnosing what went wrong esaier after all.